# I need to get filtrated array that have products only with ids from first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to get filtrated array that have products only with ids from first array. I tried something like this:

```
let first = [1, 4]
let second = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 4}]
second.filter((es, i) => es.id.includes(first))
```

[image]

Comment: You should be doing (es, i) => first.includes(es.id).  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to reverse the include condition so it should be `first.includes(es.id)` instead of `es.id.includes(first)`

```js
let first = [1, 4]
let second = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 4}]
let result=second.filter(es => first.includes(es.id))
console.log(result);
```